# How to scale current code on several threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a valid code for two threads.
The main idea of the code: Print each even number in the first thread and each odd number in the second thread.

I have to scale current code on 10 threads. E.g.

the first thread prints 0, 10, 20, ...

the second thread prints 1, 11, 21 ...

the 10th thread prints 9, 19, 29, ...

I plan to use `vector<std::thread>` but i don't want to write 10 functions.
**How can I solve the task for ten threads?**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib> // std::atoi
#include <thread> // std::thread
#include <mutex> // std::mutex
#include <condition_variable>


using namespace std;

class PrintOrder final
{
public:
    PrintOrder(int n) 
        : maxNum_(n)
        , curNum_(0)
    {
        startTime_ = chrono::steady_clock::now();
        threadEven_ = thread(&PrintOrder::even, this);
        threadOdd_ = thread(&PrintOrder::odd, this);
    }

    ~PrintOrder()
    {
        threadEven_.join();
        threadOdd_.join();

        auto endTime = chrono::steady_clock::now();
        auto diff = endTime - startTime_;
        cout << chrono::duration <double, milli> (diff).count() << " ms" << endl;
    }

    void even()
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lk(m_);
        while (curNum_ <= maxNum_)
        {
            cv_.wait(lk, [this]{ return curNum_ % 2 == 0; });
            if (curNum_ <= maxNum_)
            {
                cout << curNum_ << endl;
                ++curNum_;
            }
            cv_.notify_all();
        }
    }

    void odd()
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lk(m_);
        while (curNum_ <= maxNum_)
        {
            cv_.wait(lk, [this]{ return curNum_ % 2 != 0; });
            if (curNum_ <= maxNum_)
            {
                cout << curNum_ << endl;
                ++curNum_;
            }
            cv_.notify_all();
        }
    }
private:
    int maxNum_;
    int curNum_;
    mutex m_;
    condition_variable cv_;
    thread threadEven_, threadOdd_;

    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> startTime_;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        int num = stoi(argv[1]);

        PrintOrder printOrder(num);
    } else {
        cout << "ERROR: expected console input" << endl;
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could keep a `std::vector` of `std::thread` instead of having two hardcoded.

Example:

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

class PrintOrder final {
public:
    PrintOrder(unsigned n, unsigned threadcount) : maxNum_(n) {
        threads.reserve(threadcount);
        // create all threads giving each one a different number, x
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m_);
        for(unsigned x = 0; x < threadcount; ++x) {
            threads.emplace_back(&PrintOrder::background, this, x);
        }
    }

    ~PrintOrder() {
        // join all
        for(auto&& th : threads) th.join();
    }

    // the thread function, taking x
    void background(unsigned x) {
        while(true) {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m_);
            // wait until it's this thread's turn or curNum_ > maxNum_
            while((curNum_ % threads.size()) != x && curNum_ <= maxNum_)
                cv_.wait(lk);

            if(curNum_ > maxNum_) break; // time to quit

            std::cout << curNum_ << std::endl;
            ++curNum_;
            cv_.notify_all();
        }
    }

private:
    std::mutex m_{};
    std::condition_variable cv_{};
    std::vector<std::thread> threads{};
    unsigned curNum_ = 0;
    unsigned maxNum_;
};

int main() {
    PrintOrder printOrder(100, 10); // count to 100, using 10 threads
}
```